# Channel Videos - Display if video exists

Tags: conditionals, ee5, channel-videos, eeharbor

Confused as to why this does not work (EE5).

I have a Channel Videos field named {p_vids}.
In my template, within the channel:entries I have the below, but it doesn't display the video/code. (Displays fine without the 'if' conditional)

```
{if p_vids}

<section class="section">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <h3 class="text-center">Videos</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="row">
            {exp:channel_videos:videos entry_id="{entry_id}"}
            <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-4">
              <div class="vid">{video:embed_code}
                <h6 class="title">{video:title}</h6>
              </div>
            </div>
            {/exp:channel_videos:videos}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

{/if}
```

I cannot use/have the {if video:no_videos} within the channel_videos tag since there is the entire layout outside of that - which I Do Not want displaying unless a video(s) is/are added.

What am I missing?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution (provided by eeharbor) was to use the below 'if' statement.

```
{if '{exp:channel_videos:videos entry_id="{entry_id}" limit="1"}{video:total}{/exp:channel_videos:videos}' != ''}

code

{/if}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `{if video:no_videos}` inside the Channel Videos tag for no results. So, you should try your code in below manner.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="your_channel_name"}
<div>
    {exp:channel_videos:videos entry_id="{entry_id}"}

    {if video:no_videos}
    <p>Sorry, no videos found!!!</p>
    {/if}

    <div>{video:embed_code}
        <h6>{video:title}</h6>
    </div>

    {/exp:channel_videos:videos}
</div>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks for that but unfortunately that is not suitable (layout divs outside Channel VIdeos tag). See updated question.